# updating a xml file using javascript and jsp

Tags: javascript, xml, jsp

we are making a web UI in JSP and using a bit of Javascript .
 I need to load the xml file contents in text box and allow to edit it and write the changes to xml file.

In my code i am able to edit it but the changes are not written back to the xml file. I am putting my .jsp file below..

.jsp file

```html
    <html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
 

</style>

</head>
<body>
Title: <input type="text" id="title" value=""><br>
Id: <input type="text" id="id" value=""><br>
Updated: <input type="text" id="updated" value=""><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Save Changes</button> 
<script>
//if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  //{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  //}
//else
  //{// code for IE6, IE5
  //xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  //}
xmlhttp.open("GET","values.xml",false);
try {
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
}
catch(err) {
    alert( err.message);
}
//document.write("<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Updated</th><th>Id</th></tr>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("feed");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
 document.getElementById("title").value=x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
 document.getElementById("id").value=x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
 document.getElementById("updated").value=x[i].getElementsByTagName("updated")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  /*document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("updated")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  */
  }
//document.write("</table>");

function myFunction() {
  try{
 //document.getElementById("title").value="Hello";
 x[0].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = document.getElementById("title").value;
  x[0].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = document.getElementById("id").value;
  x[0].getElementsByTagName("updated")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = document.getElementById("updated").value;
 //document.write("<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Updated</th><th>Id</th></tr>");
 document.write("<p>");
   document.write(x[0].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</p><p>");
   document.write(x[0].getElementsByTagName("updated")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</p><p>");
   document.write(x[0].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</p>");
  
   xmlDoc.save("values.xml");
   return(xmlDoc);
   }
   catch(err) {
      alert( err.message);
  }
   //document.write("</table>");
}
 
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Example Feed

2003-12-13T18:30:02Z

urn:uuid:60a76c80-d399-11d9-b93C-0003939e0af6
   Helo work

Comment: Browser (and javascript) can't read/modify files on the filesystem

Comment: then can i do it using JSP?

Comment: You are messed between client and server. You can upload the file to the server, modify it and download it back, for sure.